# Compiling WSDLPULL with Microsoft VisulaStudio 2010 express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, soap, compiler-errors, wsdl

I am trying to compile wsdlpull (http://wsdlpull.sourceforge.net/#install) to create the dll and the tools but I cant seem to open the dsw file in to the work space with out errors as the instructions suggests. Could some who has tried this before give me a few hints as to what this might be caused by.

If not can someone  suggest a good SOAP library with LGPL license.

Comment: Does VS offer to convert the project file for you? What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: D:\wsdlpull-1.24\wsdlpull-1.24\win32\xml.dsp : error  : Project upgrade failed. This is the only error I get And yes it offer to convert the files.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the wsdlpull-1.24\win32\vs2008 directory for the Visual Studio 2008 project version and convert that.